# Анимация в Unity (прошу критики кода и метода)

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация, инспекция-кода, 2d

есть анимация ходьбы персонажа (Влево, Вправо, Вверх и Вниз) вызываемая при помощи индексов.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Существует задача** : сохранять положение анимации персонажа (оставлять спрайт персонажа повёрнутым в сторону ходьбы "речь идёт о 2D сцене").

**Для выполнения данной задачи** написал скрипт (будет ниже), а так же создал анимационные клипы в 1 кадр (Где на каждом из них - персонаж повёрнут в нужную сторону).

**Суть проблемы** - анимация долго думает перед тем как смениться, персонаж уже начинает идти, а анимация, к примеру - смотреть налево, остаётся и только через пол секунды (может меньше) сменяется (Exit time на каждом переходе выставил на 0).

**Думаю, проблема в скрипте или моём методе** реализации данной процедуры. Прошу помощи и критики, заранее спасибо!
 (Мой скрипт)

```
Animator _anim;
bool a;
    bool d;
    bool w;
    bool s;
void Start()
{
    a = false;
    d = false;
    w = false;
    s = false;
    _anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); 
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    if (h == -1)
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 3);
        a = true;

    }
    else if (h == 1)
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 4);
        d = true;
    }
    else if (v == 1)
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
        w = true;
    }
    else if (v == -1 )
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 2);
        s = true;
    }
    else if (a == true && d == false && w == false && s == false)
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 7);
        a = false;
    }
    else if (d == true && a == false && w == false && s == false)
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 6);
        d = false;
    }
    else if (w == true && d == false && a == false && s == false)
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 8);
        w = false;
    }
    else if (s == true && d == false && w == false && a == false)
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 5);
        s = false;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что проверка у Вас осуществляется в FixedUpdate. Попробуйте управлять анимацией из Update. Если анимация после этого по-прежнему будет работать "не адекватно", то приложите скриншот машины состояний аниматора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в этих `if (h == -1)` строках. Значение Input.GetAxis хоть вертикальная, хоть горизонтальная не сразу становится -1 или 1, а постепенно, с шагом 0.05f. [Note: The Horizontal and Vertical ranges change from 0 to +1 or -1 with increase/decrease in 0.05f steps. GetAxisRaw has changes from 0 to 1 or -1 immediately, so with no steps.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) Соответственно у вас и меняется анимация когда доберется до значения 1 или -1. Вам надо делать проверки такого рода: `if (h > 0){...} if (h < 0) {...}`. По поводу FixedUpdate() или Update() [там же сказано:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) This is frame-rate independent; you do not need to be concerned about varying frame-rates when using this value, поэтому делайте в зависимости от вашей логики.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы действительно решили мою проблему. Я не знал, что значения Input.GetAxis присваиваются таким образом, сейчас исправил - всё работает. По поводу FixedUpdate - изначально пробовал менять Update на FixedUpdate ничего не менялось, теперь знаю почему.

Comment: Одно но - у меня в скрипте была ошибка ещё одна, по поводу одновременного нажатия нескольких клавиш, сейчас я уже всё исправил. Где мне лучше оставить новый код, для того, чтобы другие смогли посмотреть, если нужно будет кому? В свой вопрос залить или как ответ оформить?

Comment: @Vasiliy, если этот код действительно полноценно отвечает на ваш вопрос - оформите его как ответ, но с пояснениями, пустой код вряд ли поможет новичкам.

Comment: И в общем случае автор этого ответа не прав: хоть GetAxis и не зависим от кадровой частоты, это не значит, что от частоты кадров не зависит и input lag. Может, у кого-то физический апдейт будет вызван 2 раза в секунду, кидать туда input`ы было бы ошибкой. А фраза "you do not need to be concerned about varying frame-rates when using this value" говорит о том, что не нужно подстраивать код под кадровую частоту, что логично.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, И чем посоветуете заменить Input?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Прошу проверить мои пояснения, я в C# новичок и мог что-либо объяснить неверно и тем самым введу в заблуждение других новичков.

Comment: @Vasiliy, Input ничем не нужно заменять, просто нужно его ставить _в общем случае_ в Update, а не FixedUpdate. Насчет вашего ответа, не совсем понял, зачем вам нужны 4 булевых значения? Вы вместо установки этой переменной можете в том месте включать определенную анимацию.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Для того, чтобы реализовать следующую вещь - персонаж шёл налево, остановился и смотрит в ту сторону, в которую шёл. Итого, 4 значения мне нужны для определения последней нажатой кнопки (в какую сторону двигался персонаж). Если у Вас есть другой вариант или я не понял тот, что Вы написали выше. Объясните, пожалуйста, подробнее.

Comment: @Vasiliy, прочел ваш код еще раз, решение не самое "ровное", но рабочее. Единственное - уберите проверки всех 4х переменных в if`ах, в любом случае в отдельный момент времени только одна переменная будет true, так что надобность в проверке других переменных на false отсутствует.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Да, действительно, Вы правы. Эти проверки это пережиток прошлого кода. Теперь в них действительно нет нужды. Завтра уберу и обновлю ответ.По поводу - не самое "ровное" - если есть предложения, буду рад попробовать по вашему совету.

Comment: @Vasiliy, добавьте вашу машину состояний в виде скриншота, гораздо проще сделать грамотный переход в ней, нежели запоминать, в какую сторону двигался объект. Такой подход в принципе уберет эти проверки и лишние переменные.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Прошу прощения, долго не мог добраться до юнити. Скинул Вам машину состояний.

Comment: @Vasiliy, не очень понимаю, почему у вас присутствует состояние "off", ведь персонаж всегда будет смотреть в какую-то сторону, разве нет? Или это такое "idle" состояние, в которое персонаж переходит по истечению какого-то времени?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, это я просто не переименовал "смотреть вниз"

Comment: @Vasiliy, добавил ответ

Answer (score 1):

В итоге - получился вот такой код, который исправно работает.

P.s. Спасибо добрым людям.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Anim : MonoBehaviour {
Animator _anim;
    bool a; // Создаём переменные которые могут иметь значения (true или false).
    bool d; // И будем их использовать для определения - была ли нажата клавиша или нет. 
    bool w;
    bool s;
void Start() // При запуске программы, делаем переменные равными - false (Кнопка не была нажата) 
{
    a = false;
    d = false;
    w = false;
    s = false;
    _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update() // В данной функции действия происходят каждый кадр
{ 
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); // Создаём переменную, которая будет принимать значение (-1 , 0 , 1) в зависимости от горизонтального перемещения
                                           // Тем самым, сообщая, какая клавиша нажата - если -1 то "А", если 1 то "D", если 0 то не нажата
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");// Создаём переменную, которая будет принимать значение (-1 , 0 , 1) в зависимости от вертикального перемещения
                                        // Тем самым, сообщая, какая клавиша нажата - если -1 то "S", если 1 то "W", если 0 то не нажата

    if (h < 0) // Если нажата кнопка налево (В моём случае это - "A"), выполнить следующее 
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 3); //Сменить индекс проигрываемой анимации, тем самым сменив её 
        a = true; // Задать значение переменной "a" - true

        d = false;// Остальные переменный, как и в каждом последующем случае, мы делаем равными "false" ибо мы не всегда 
                  // будем двигаться в одну сторону, возможно движение и наискосок, посредством одновременного нажатия двух клавиш
                  // а для данного метода включения анимации, необходимо иметь не более одной переменной со значением "true"
        w = false;
        s = false;

    }
    else if (h > 0)// Если нажата кнопка направо (В моём случае это - "D"), выполнить следующее 
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 4); // Здесь действия одни и те же, лишь меняется индекс анимации и переменная, которая станет - true
        d = true;
        a = false;
        w = false;
        s = false;
    }
    else if (v > 0)// Если нажата кнопка вверх (В моём случае это - "W"), выполнить следующее 
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
        w = true;
        d = false;
        a = false;
        s = false;
    }
    else if (v < 0)// Если нажата кнопка вниз (В моём случае это - "S"), выполнить следующее 
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 2);
        s = true;
        d = false;
        w = false;
        a = false;
    }

    else if (a == true && d == false && w == false && s == false)// На данном этапе, осуществляется проверка - какая клавиша была нажата
                                                                 // тем самым, определяя в какую сторону мы двигались и запуская соответствующую анимацию
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 7);
        a = false; // После того, как наша анимация, в данном случае (смотреть налево), включена. Нужно вернуть переменную "a" в значение - false
    }
    else if (d == true && a == false && w == false && s == false)
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 6);
        d = false;
    }
    else if (w == true && d == false && a == false && s == false)
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 8);
        w = false;
    }
    else if (s == true && d == false && w == false && a == false)
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", 5);
        s = false;
    }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Довольно странный у вас автомат в плане переходов. Если объект движется, например вправо, то встать в неподвижную позу вправо - `RightStay` он может только **после** движения вправо, но никак не из любого состояния.

В итоге машина состояний становится чуть более логичной, что ли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что по логике вашего кода, что просто по человеческой логике начать **смотреть вправо** только после того, как персонаж **двигался вправо**. Такое работает со всеми направлениями.

---

Я использовал точно такие же номера состояний для переходов, как и у вас в коде - конфликтов быть не должно.

Также в аниматор был добавлен триггер, переключение которого будет условием перехода из состояния движения в состояния "простоя":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для всех переходов от движения в любую сторону в "простой" в соответствующую сторону нужно добавить вот такой переход от нового триггера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Ну и наконец финальный код, который, прошу заметить, очень сильно убавил в количестве строк и ненужных проверок с кучей ненужных булевых значений :)

```
public class Anim : MonoBehaviour {

    Animator _anim;

    void Start () {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update () {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (h < 0) {
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 3);
        }
        else if (h > 0) {
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 4);
        }
        else if (v > 0) {
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
        }
        else if (v < 0) {
            _anim.SetInteger("State", 2);
        }
        else {
            // выставляет несуществующее состояние, чтобы не сработал переход
            // AnyState -> MoveState
            // по-хорошему это НЕ нужно выставлять каждый кадр
            // лучше запомнить h и v предыдущего кадра, если предыдущий кадр
            // и текущий равны - выставление State`а можно опустить
            _anim.SetInteger("State", -1);
            // вот такая простая манипуляция c конечным автоматом
            // позволяет легко перейти в соответствующее idle состояние
            // если мы находимся в движении - будет выбрана верная сторона
            // если мы не двигаемся - триггер поменяет состояние, но ничего не поменяется
            _anim.SetTrigger("Stopped");
        }
    }
}
```